# Can a group of order $m$ have an element of order $n$ such that $n\!\not|\: m$

Tags: group-theory

Can a group of order $m$ have an element of order $n$ such that $n\!\not|\: m$?

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no, but I'm not sure how to disprove this statement. What theorems could I use to prove/disprove it?

Comment: [Theorem of Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) applied on subgroup generated by element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lagrange's Theorem tells us that for finite groups, the order of a subgroup necessarily divides the order of the group. Can you see how this gives us the result we need?

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is an element of order $n$ th in a group $G$ then $$H=\{1,a,a^2 ,...,a^{n-1}\}$$ i as subgroup of order $n$ hence $n=|H| $ divides $|G|=m.$

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of [Lagrange theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), the answer is no.